# Custom blacklist for firefox AwesomeBar?

Tags: firefox, search, filter, firefox-addon

Former title: Custom filter for firefox/greasemonkey search suggestions?

For work I have a few internal websites like "foo.site.com" or "bar.site.com" that I have dozens of bookmarks and history entries for.
Firefox has settings to toggle between bookmarks, history, both, neither, but none of those work for me, since they either disable it completely, or spam me with these unwanted sites.

I am looking for an addon, or if none exists, pointers on how to start writing the addon (specific methods, attributes to tinker with, etc?)
E.g. change the action when i open a tab and type "foo": "is site in history/bookmarks? display it"
to: "is site in hist/bookmarks? is it blacklisted in this file? display it"

I want to keep the bookmarks and history, as well as the search-suggestions for both bookmarks and history. I want to block foo.site.com from showing up in those suggestions regardless of whether its bookmarked, etc.
Going back and manually tagging hundreds of bookmarks is not going to work either.

Comment: You're trying to add a blacklist to the "AwesomeBar"?  If so, then Greasemonkey cannot do that.  You need to write a Firefox add-on.  See also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/148310

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking to do. Sorry but I have been searching, and haven't found anything on stackoverflow to do with the awesomebar that isn't "replicate functionality in my own app"